# Remove Ubuntu bootloader from Windows 7 dual boot

Tags: bootloader

I have an old hard drive that I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a few weeks ago, and a new hard drive which has Windows 7 installed. I am using these in a dual boot. I am using the Windows 7 bootloader and I added Ubuntu through a program called EasyBCD. This worked perfectly, untill I updated Ubuntu. Now when I choose Ubuntu from the Windows 7 bootloader, it takes me to the Ubuntu bootloader (on the second hard drive), which makes me choose what OS to boot again. How can I disable/skip this second bootloader? (I want to use the Windows 7 bootloader, and not swap).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You very well may want that bootloader one day! ;)

But try this and see if you like it:

`sudo -i gedit /etc/default/grub`

Look for:

'GRUB_TIMEOUT=10'

Change that to 0. This will make the countdown on the grub screen 0, and it will boot the default OS. **MAKE SURE Ubuntu is your default selection, or it will just boot back to windows!**

Then:

`sudo update-grub`

Comment: It might just be being silly, but I changed 'GRUB_TIMEOUT=10' to 'GRUB_TIMEOUT=0' and ran 'sudo update-grub' and rebooted, selected Ubuntu from the Windows boot manager, and it loaded right back into the Grub bootloader and didnt skip it. Also, how do I make sure Ubuntu is the default OS to boot in Grub?

Comment: well the order they show up in the grub menu is the order, and it starts at 0 from the top I believe. Read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Boot_Display_Behavior

Can you get into ubuntu still ?

Comment: Yes, I can still access ubuntu, but for some reason it wont bypass the grub menu. Ubuntu shows as the first option in the grub bootloader and the config file says 'GRUB_DEFAULT=0' so yes Ubuntu is the default option.

Comment: Try editing the following lines so they match these:
`GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`

Also be sure to:
`sudo update-grub`

Afterwards

Comment: The lines match exactly as you wrote them, and I have definitely ran sudo update-grub. I did it again to make sure. Grub still loads and counts 10 seconds. Is there anything I can do apart from switch to grub?

Comment: It still counts from 10 even after changing timeout to 0 ? Hmmmm, Are any of those said lines commented out by chance?

Comment: The lines don't seem to be commented, they certainly don't have any '#' symbols before them. Here is my entire config file. [Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/5vLzgcE1)

Comment: I'm sorry looks like im a little outdated. You can't use a 0 in:

`GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`

Try putting a "1" there instead. My Bad. Also one last thing I thought of you can try is the following change:

`GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false`

Make that line identical, or add it. If that doesn't fix your problem, I am out of ideas and hopefully someone else can step in ^_^

Comment: Changing the 0 to a 1 in 'GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0' worked and made the timer 1 second. Thanks for your help. Would it be possible to change this to a smaller value, such as '0.0001' to make grub display for an even shorter time, or would this be incompatible with the grub loader? Thanks again.

Comment: Well you can try "0" again just in case I was wrong ;) but at this point, you know as much as I do sir, you'll have to play around a bit to get desired results, glad I could get you one step closer!

Comment: I changed it to 'GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0.1' and it did not even display the bootloader, everything is working perfectly, just the same as before the update. Thanks one more time for your help.

Comment: No Problem! Take note of changes made, in case you ever want to reverse this! Holding shift during boot I think should get the menu back, although I can't confirm.