# Remove GRUB boot selecting after Windows is gone

Tags: grub2, bootloader, removing

I've been looking for this answer quite a while in the last few days, but all google and question searches here seem to retrieve are for removing grub and restoring Windows's bootloader after deleting Ubuntu from a dual-box.

My case is the opposite: I had a dual box and decided to remove Windows; I've already removed the partition and merged it accordingly with Ubuntu's, and i'm not having problems with booting my Ubuntu.

Still, I would like to REMOVE the grub selection screen when I turn on my laptop, so that it goes straight into Ubuntu; so far I've tried updating the grub with `sudo update-grub` and it only removed the now unexistant-windows entries.

Can I get some guidance on the process please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/480617/remove-ubuntu-bootloader-from-windows-7-dual-boot/480621?noredirect=1#comment639200_480621 read my answer and comments here, this should let you skip the GRUB screen.

Answer (score 1):

Even after using **sudo update-grub** command

If still Windows boot manager shows in GNU grub then try these commands in Terminal:

**sudo rm -r /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft**   then

**sudo update-grub**

This will work fine and reboot your System.

Comment: I did that, and I also used `efibootmgr` to remove the Windows install. I am not sure if this additional step is really required or not.

Answer (score 0):

The blog post http://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/grub2-revisited/ revisited will provide you with a blow-by-blow set of instructions on how to manually edit GRUB2's configuration files. If you check the other postings in the series (by filtering on Category = GRUB) you will also find information on removing old kernels and what happens when a new kernel arrives as an update. The postings include references to a number of related web sites.

Comment: I'm less than a month's worth noob in Ubuntu, but that blog entry seems to be trying to handle new kernel releases being included into the boot menu and trying not to break anything.

Please correct me if i'm wrong, but my problem is actually wanting no boot menu at all (does this cause problems when updating Ubuntu into new kernels ?)

Comment: It doesn't work like that. Sorry! Grub has to show up no matter what.

Comment: It does even when, say, I install Linux on a completely blank, unpartitioned disk ? that's interestig to know

Answer (score 0):

Not ubuntu, but https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Hide_GRUB_unless_the_Shift_key_is_held_down should be helpful; basic gist is placing a custom script in `/etc/grub.d` which gets included in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` when you run update-grub; script is lengthy so I'll not post here.

Comment: This is not what I was originally requesting but seems like an interesting alternative; thanks for bringing it in.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing Grub Customizer with the following commands in the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Once this is installed, run it (should show in the dash) and go to the "general settings" tab. In here there is a section called "visibility". See if "show menu" or "look for other operating systems" is ticked and untick them, choose save and then reboot and see if it is fixed.

There may be a flag set to show menu anyhow. The other reason it can show the grub menu is if there is an error being reported and it suspects you want to boot into recovery mode. In this case you would need to find out what error and fix it.